# dynamic id is not working for table rows on cloning

Tags: jquery, html

i have a table with clone the rows option . When i clone a row for the a tag input id is `text_0` not changing its taking previous input id.
I want a tag input id should get incremented like `text_1`,`text_2`,'`text_3`...so on when we clone a row.
Below is the Html :

```
<table class="" id="table-data">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th> Qty</th>
      <th>days</th>
      <th>rate</th>
      <th>rowtotal</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" autocomplete="off" name="qty[]" placeholder="Qty" class="form-control Qty">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" autocomplete="off" name="days[]" placeholder="Days" class="form-control Days">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" autocomplete="off" name="rate[]" placeholder="Rate" class="form-control rate">
      </td>

      <td>
        <input type="text" autocomplete="off" readonly="" name="row_total[]" id="row_total0" placeholder="Row    Total" class="form-control rowTotal">
        <a class="Comment" data-toggle="modal"  data-target="#commentModal"><input type="" id="text_0"></a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm" role="group" aria-label="">
          <button type="button" class="addline btn btn-sm btn-primary">+</button>
          <button type="button" class="delete btn btn-sm btn-danger">-</button>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Jquery :

```
$(document).on('click', '.addline', function () {
  var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
  var $lastTr = $tr.closest('table').find('tr:last');
  var $clone = $lastTr.clone();
  $clone.find('td').each(function () {
    var el = $(this).find(':first-child');
    var id = el.attr('id') || null;
    if (id) {
      var i = id.substr(id.length - 1);
      var prefix = id.substr(0, (id.length - 1));
      el.attr('id', prefix + (+i + 1));
    }
  });

  $clone.find('input:text').val('');
  $tr.closest('tbody').append($clone);

});
$(document).on('click', '.delete', function () {
  //dont delete the last data row
  var parentId = $(this).closest('table').attr('id');

  if ($('#' + parentId + '  tr').length > 2) {
    var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    $tr.remove();
  }
  return false;
});
```

How do i change id for the a tag input also . Any suggestions please ?

[js fiddle demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/fyhsz9ra/1262/)

Comment: fiddle seems worki fine ,!!

Comment: @blackandorangecat : yes its not even being added and when i clone a row its taking the before input id and incrementing . any solution for it ?

Comment: waht's the matter , it increment correctly ! in the fiddle !

Comment: I'm confused what you expect the output to look like. The fiddle is changing the `ID` of the input.

Comment: @bRIMOs : no its not . a tag input id is `text_0` but its not taking and not incrementing

Comment: @blackandorangecat : a tag input is `text_0` i need that increment like `text_1`,`text_2` .. so on when you clone a row . But that is not happening. Please check in the console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code/behavior is a little confusing, but it appears that `el` is a collection of length 2, matching both of the parent elements for the `id`s you want to modify.  But since you're not looping over `el`, only one `id` is being set.  And in classic jQuery style, it's silently happening to everything on the matched set:

```
el.attr('id', prefix + (+i + 1));
```

Instead, loop over `el` and set each one individually.  Something like this:

```
var el = $(this).find(':first-child');
$(el).each(function () {  // loop over the matched set here
  var id = $(this).attr('id') || null;  // target the item in the loop
  if (id) {
    debugger;
    var i = id.substr(id.length - 1);
    var prefix = id.substr(0, (id.length - 1));
    $(this).attr('id', prefix + (+i + 1));  // target the item in the loop
  }
});
```

[Updated jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fyhsz9ra/1263/)